# addView directly after removeView only working when new View contains a Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a very strange problem. Let me first describe the structure of the views:

- MainActivity

  - CoordinatorLayout

    - AppBarLayout

      - CollapsingToolbarLayout

        - FloatingActionButton
        - ToolBar
    - NestedScrollView

      - TableLayout

        - TextView (many)
        - Button (optional)

What I'm trying to do is replacing the one NestedScrollView object with another according to user actions. I have created the following method for this:

```
public void switchTableGroup(final TableGroup newTG){
    final NestedScrollView removeNSV = currentNSV;
    Thread switchView = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            mainCoordinatorLayout.removeView(removeNSV);
            mainCoordinatorLayout.addView(newTG.getNestedScrollView());
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(switchView);
    this.currentTG = newTG;
    this.currentNSV = newTG.getNestedScrollView();
}
```

(note that the TableGroup is a non-graphical object for my internal data structure) This works fine as long as there is at least one Button object in the underlying TableLayout. If there is no Button object present, the old NestedScrollView is removed and the new one is written into currentNSV and added to the CoordinatorLayout, but somehow not invisible. With some dirty code this problem can be solved:

```
  public void switchTableGroupDirty(final TableGroup newTG){
     final NestedScrollView removeNSV = currentNSV;
     Thread switchView = new Thread(){
         public void run(){
             mainCoordinatorLayout.removeView(removeNSV);
             mainCoordinatorLayout.addView(newTG.getNestedScrollView());
         }
     };
     runOnUiThread(switchView);
     this.currentTG = newTG;
     this.currentNSV = newTG.getNestedScrollView();
     Thread doItAgain = new Thread(){
         public void run(){
             mainCoordinatorLayout.removeView(newTG.getNestedScrollView());
             mainCoordinatorLayout.addView(newTG.getNestedScrollView());
         }
     };
     runOnUiThread(doItAgain);
}
```

I don't want to depend on doing something twice, is there some specific command to force the CoordinatorLayout to redraw itself? I have already tried invalidate() and refreshDrawableState() on the CoordinatorLayout object, but this didn't help. Also spent a lot of time on trying various combinations, with sleeping etc. You can also imagine it took quite some time to isolate that the presence of the Button was the key factor to the success of the normal method...

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding / removing views on a separate thread?

Comment: The method can get called from another thread. if you don't encapsulate that in a method that is ran on the UI Thread it won't show for sure. Also see: [android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html). Of course I could have used a Runnable as well in this case, Thread implements Runnable.